# Raspian: Multiple IP addresses are created on eth0

Tags: linux, raspbian

When trying to initiate docker swarm, I get the following error response from daemon:

```
 could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on interface eth0 (aa11:a111:1a1a::111 and ba11:a111:1a1a::111).
```

When I execute:

```
 sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
```

I successfully remove all ip addresses, however, they are recreated once I reboot. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: That looks more like a bug to me, since this actually seems to be twice the same address.

Comment: I did anonymise those addresses

Comment: Uninstall NetworkManager and check /etc/network/interfaces.